# AsyncTask executes Serial instead of Parallel (HTTPost TimeOutException)

Tags: java, android

> **EDIT:** AsyncTask was called lots of times to update status in Server
>   and at the same time, my app tried to upload files. AsyncTask by
>   default, do only one operation at a time (serial mode) but you can put
>   it in Parallel mode, as I answered below.

After running normally during several hours (and sometimes a few minutes), my app stops connecting to the server with HTTPost. I set the Timeout to 20 sec and It's a good time since the connection is good (wifi). I have tested it in two servers: my own computer and a virtual private server. The problem happens equally.

Is there some way or reason for Android to avoid connecting to the http server?
Is there another reason for this to happen?
Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks!!

### This is how I make a POST request:

```
try{
        new ConexaoHTTPPost.SolicitaDados(parametros).execute(url).get(20000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            new ReportException(getApplicationContext()).send(e,classeToErr);
                        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                            new ReportException(getApplicationContext()).send(e,classeToErr);
                        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                            new ReportException(getApplicationContext()).send(e,classeToErr);
                        }
```

---

### HTTPost Code:

```
public class ConexaoHTTPPost {
    public static String postDados(String urlUsuario, String parametrosUsuario) {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(urlUsuario);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Lenght","" + Integer.toString(parametrosUsuario.getBytes().length));
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language","pt-BR");
            connection.setUseCaches(false); 
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
            outputStreamWriter.write(parametrosUsuario);
            outputStreamWriter.flush();
            outputStreamWriter.close();

            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));

            StringBuffer resposta = new StringBuffer();

            String linha;
            while ( (linha = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                resposta.append(linha);
                resposta.append('\r');
            }

            bufferedReader.close();

            return resposta.toString();
        }catch (Exception erro){
            return null;
        }finally {
            if(connection != null){
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class SolicitaDados extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private String parametros;
        //private String resultado = null;

        public SolicitaDados(String parametros) {
            this.parametros = parametros;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            return ConexaoHTTPPost.postDados(urls[0], parametros);
        }
        /*
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String resultado){
            this.resultado = resultado;
        }
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: After this error happen, I pinged the server and everything is ok

Comment: `new ConexaoHTTPPost.SolicitaDados(parametros).execute(url).get(`  ?? Are you starting an `AsyncTask` and then calling the `.get()` on it?

Comment: This is the way I found to set a TimeOut. I'm a newbie programmer yet.

Comment: Why would that set an time out? Nonsense! You should do without the .get() if it is indeed an asynctask. (Why didnt you confirm?). Redesign the logic to do wihout .get().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved It. 
I was using **execute()** method but, actually, the correct way is to use **executeOnExecutor()** in this line:

> new ConexaoHTTPPost.SolicitaDados(parametros).execute(url).get(20000,
>   TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

**execute()** executes everything in serial in the UI Thread, so you can't upload two files (or data) at the same time because the connection get blocked by the UI thread.

When using executeOnExecutor() method, you can upload multiple files ou data. I had only to change this line as shown:

> new ConexaoHTTPPost.SolicitaDados(parametros).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,
>   url).get(20000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

I changed it in all places it appears.
PS: You have to use **AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR** as a Thread Executor.